# Can HTML5 Local Storage Be Viewed and Edited in Visual Studio Debugger for Windows Cordova App

Tags: local-storage, visual-studio-cordova

Is there a way to display, or even better, edit HTML5 local storage data in a Cordova Universal Windows app in the Visual Studio debugger, like one can in Google Chrome for a web application? So far I haven't found any references to this on the web or the VS documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way to check the Local Storage values from visual studio

use the javascript console and execute this line of code **window.localStorage** then it will show the list of values from there change the values using the setItem method.

there is no GUI to see the local storage values as same as Google Chrome devtools.